# Python: Doing an FFT on a .wav file

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to do an FFT on a .wav file that contains only a 1 kHz sin wave. When I plot the result, I expect the peak to be at the fundamental (1 kHz) but instead, I see the peak at what seems to be the 3rd harmonic (3 kHz). I have tried 2 other .wav files at 440 Hz and 2 kHz with the same result. I used a frequency counter to verify the .wav files contain the frequencies I expect.

For comparison, I use the commented code below to generate and plot a sin function which displays correctly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave, struct


sound_file = wave.open('c:\downloads\SineWave_1000Hz.wav', 'r')
file_length = sound_file.getnframes()
data = sound_file.readframes(file_length)
data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=file_length), data)
data = np.array(data)
sound_file.close()

#x = np.linspace(0.0, 1, 600)
#y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
#yf = fft(y)
yf = fft(data)

plt.xlim(0, 4000)
plt.plot( np.abs(yf))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: if your synthetic data plot correctly, but your wav file does not, there's probably an issue with the data.  Are you sure your frequency counter is right?  Plot the data from the wav file and see if it comes up as expected. An x3 change in the data might have to do with whether you do/don't multiply by pi?

Comment: Thanks! I verified that my frequency counter is correct and I also verified my .wav freq with a scope. I'm wondering if I am changing the data when unpacking and converting to a numpy array. I'm wondering if I'm properly unpacking and formatting  the return from readframes...